# JQuery scroll to top of page

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to programmatically scroll to the top of a page with jQuery? I am currently trying to do this with the following code but it is not working. I am using Firefox currently,

```
$(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
```

You can do this with `0` instead of `300` to be instant, but this gives a quick auto-scroll effect.

Comment: I wanted the jQueryUI dialog widget to scroll to the top at launch and this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding a snippet to Nick's nice answer.  This shows your "scroll to top" element only after the user has scrolled down the page some, i.e. Pinterest-style.

```
  $("#scroll_to_top_button").hide(); // hide on page load

  $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 200) { // show after 200 px of user scrolling
      $("#scroll_to_top").slideDown("fast");
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for jQuery here. Use native:

`window.scrollTo(x-coordinate, y-coordinate);`

*Note that this has no control over animate part (duration etc.) that jQuery provides*

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
   if( target.length ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
   }
});
```

Add this to the HTML

```
<div id="top"></div>
<a href="#top">Click to scroll up</a>
```